# fadein element on hovering same or other element?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

since I think this isn’t a very complex task I searched stackoverflow several times with different searches. but since I don’t really know how to describe the searched solution in a few words all searches failed.

this is a code I use to bring up a navigation when the page loads, fade it out after 4 seconds and fade it back in when hovering the navigation-div – and fading it out when the mouse leaves:

```
$(".navigation").delay(4000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
$(".navigation").on({
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).delay(200).fadeTo(100, 0);
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
    }
});
```

now I am looking for added code that let the navigation fade in while the navigation-div itself OR another div-element is hovered … and fade out the navigation-div when this div itself or the other one is left with the mouse.

can I beef up this code to achieve this or do I need something different?

thank you very much! 
matthias

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by sharing an important piece of information that can help you solve this issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget

Here you can see that both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` have a `relatedTarget` property in their event data. It references the "coming from" or "going to" element respectively.

Below I have prototyped a solution where divs A and B act as "connected" in terms of mousein and mouseout. 
During `mouseenter` I only execute the handler if the "coming from" element is neither A nor B. 
During `mouseleave` I only execute the handler if the "going to" element is neither A nor B.

```js
$('.show-navigation').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('show-navigation')) {
    console.log('Show Navigation');
  }
});

$('.show-navigation').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('show-navigation')) {
    console.log('Hide Navigation');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="show-navigation">Element A</div>
<div id="b" class="show-navigation">Element B</div>
<div id="c">Element C</div>
```

Comment: aah, what a quick reply – thank you, I’ll try it out now. and thank you for the link! I already was on jquery’s website but the solutions I tried faded everything in or out but not the navigation.

Comment: ok, I tried the code and see what it is doing. but how can I "implement" this into my code? I am not very good with js and the above code took me days to figure out because there are so many ways to do it. 

I hoped it could be something like adding an additional class/element to the mouseenter-function, to trigger the fade in with another element too.

Comment: I dont know your html and the detailed specifics of your setup. What I proposed is just a concept. I suggest you take your time and try to implement it yourself.